# Kubernetes - HPA replicas issue

Tags: kubernetes

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: myservice
  namespace: mynamespace
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: myservice
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 3
  metrics:
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: memory
      targetAverageValue: 700Mi
```

After 15 min, i see REPLICAS grown up to 2. Since then it's not coming down.

```
C:\Users\myuser>kubectl get hpa
NAME            REFERENCE                  TARGETS           MINPODS   MAXPODS   REPLICAS   AGE
myservice    Deployment/myservice    490412032/700Mi          1         3         2          4h14m
```

There is no traffic to these services, as shown below MEMORY is well below 700Mi (as mentioned in HPA metrics).

```
C:\Users\myuser>kubectl top pod
NAME                                     CPU(cores)   MEMORY(bytes)
myservice-6ff6bdc8d-jx4pc             29m          463Mi
myservice-6ff6bdc8d-zktnm             29m          471Mi
```

I am puzzled why the 2nd replica has got created and why it's not going down ? Am i missingl something ? please suggest.

Comment: Doesn't the average value take the total for all pods into account and not for juste one pod?

Comment: That's what my question about, if the first pod memory is 463Mi, why it has created 2nd pod ?

Comment: The accepted answer is correct. However, keep in mind that memory usage is often not a suitable scaling metric because it is not "fluid". For example, adding an additional replica does not necessarily decrease the memory usage of the existing replicas (it might be the case in some applications, but often it isn't). CPU usage is generally a better scaling metric.

Comment: @weibeld thanks for pointing it out. My application is memory intensive, not CPU intensive. What you suggest here ?

Comment: Probably CPU utilisation instead of memory utilisation. You just need to change `memory` to `cpu` and adapt the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The reason it's not going down:*

The way the HPA controller calculates the number of replicas is

```
desiredReplicas = ceil[currentReplicas * ( currentMetricValue / desiredMetricValue )]
```

In your case the `currentMetricValue` is calculated from the average of the given metric across the pods, so `(463 + 471)/2 = 467Mi` because of the `targetAverageValue` being set.

The `desiredMetricValue` is 700Mi, so the `desiredReplicas` are

```
ceil[2 * (467 / 700)] = ceil[1.34] = 2
```

as ceil(x) will give you the smallest integer that is greater or equal to x.

---

*The reason it went up:*

Assuming the first pod was at about 463Mi, the `desiredReplicas` are

```
ceil[2 * (463 / 700)] = ceil[1.32] = 2
```

So if you want it to be only one pod for that workload, the `targetAbsoluteValue` needs to be at least 950Mi.