# GKE horizontal autoscaler creating revisions of the workload

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, autoscaling, horizontal-pod-autoscaling

I have a deployment that is being scaled with a HorizontalPodAutoscaler, recently out of the blue it started spamming revisions every few minutes and shutting down and creating new pods. I'm also pretty sure that these actions were not caused by the need to scale (our users remained low).

Although removing the autoscaler stopped the creation of these revisions, I'm still not sure of the cause. Aren't revisions only created when a deployment is changed, not when it is being scaled up/down?

Comment: Do you mean **replicas** instead of "revisions"? I am kind of confused. There is a similar post talking about [HPA replicas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59267605/kubernetes-hpa-replicas-issue) issue.

Comment: No, in the revision history it says a new revision is being created every ~2 min. The # of replicas stayed the same, but the pods were being spun up and terminated whenever a new revision was created.

Comment: Have you thought to use [stateless applications](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/stateless-apps) for now, while you inspect what is changing your [workloads](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/dashboards#workloads) producing those continuous revisions?

Comment: I believe the current application is stateless, do you have any suggestions on what could be changing the workload? The only events I can think of that would change it are redeployments, but the yaml is the exact same (with the exception of hashes, uuids, and timestamps), and this is happening without any submissions to the k8s api

Comment: Not sure, could you please add the deployment yaml file of the workload, attaching it to the  above question, as well as including the configuration of the cluster. Best solution may be to open a support case to  investigate it further.

Comment: You also may check if the [revision history limit](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#revision-history-limit) has been modified in your deployment.

Comment: Please could you check if there are any missing ingress firewall rules so that the GKE masters are unable to talk to the GKE nodes including the metrics server.